# How to use packages in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, adobe

I've seen other people ask this for specific types of JS, but for a 'vanilla' JS version, I want to use the flash.net package from Adobe on my webpage, but how do I use it? Do I need to install it somehow?

Comment: First of all, Flash is dead. Second, that's seems to be an ActionScript package, not a node package. In general, if you to use packages (from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/)) you need to install nodeJS. It comes with npm. No look for tutorials, like this one: https://nodesource.com/blog/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm/

Comment: @ChrisG, has Emperor Ming finally killed him?!? XP (apologies, for the bad joke; I could not resist)

Answer (score 1):

To use packages in javascript you mostly will need to use a package manager.

For instance, the most popular package manager is [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). You need first to install nodejs+npm and then install packages into your project with:

```
npm i package-name
```

Where package-name is the name for your package. You can just search for packages directly in the npm search e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=flash

The most of them have explanations of how to install them and how to import and use.